# Are "Sprachaneignung" and "Spracherwerb" synonymous?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

I am studying language teaching at university in a German speaking country. I was wondering if "Sprachaneignung" and "Spracherwerb" are synonymous or if there are some differences in usage or meaning between them. My professor seems to use it indiscriminately but I am not 100% sure about it. 
In English I would say "Language Acquisition" for both of them.

Comment: There are differences between both your terms and *Sprache erlernen* (with regards to a conscious decision and active lerning vs. intuitively picking up a language due to social interaction), but I think your two terms can be considered synonyms

Comment: @tofro please don't use comments to answer questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are synonymous. "Spracherwerb" is more common term.